# What does NO_SECURITY do in Jetty's ServletContextHandler?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I assume it just disables all of the features related to authentication, but iIt's been hard to find documentation that explicitly discusses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `options` parameter in the constructor is an old feature of `ServletContextHandler` (well before Jetty 4.x)

Here's how it works:

`options` is a set of bit flags for major servlet features that should be defaulted by `ServletContextHandler` or not.

Using `NO_SECURITY` means that the default `SecurityHandler` is not created. (for Jetty 9.3, it would be the `org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler` implementation)

Using `NO_SESSION` means that the default `SessionHandler` is not created.

However, you can still manually add the `SecurityHandler` and/or `SessionHandler` implementation or configuration of your choice after the constructor (and before `.start()`)